# Difference vfat and fat

Tags: formatting, fat32, vfat

I would like to format a USB Stick, but can't tell if the proper command is
`mkfs.vfat [device]` or `mkfs.fat -F32 -I [device]`.

I've seen both, but what is the difference between `vfat`and `fat`? they're even separate files under `which vfat`/`which fat`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928982/what-is-the-difference-between-vfat-and-fat32-file-systems  short answer, use FAT32 unless you are working with Win95 or prior.

Comment: It’s 2021, not 2004. Don’t use either, use exFAT for larger file sizes and maximum compatibility.

Comment: @MikeScott how come it came FAT32 by fabric?

Answer (score 3):

`mkfs.fat` is the current name of the tool. The older name `mkfs.vfat` is a symlink to it. However, it's still the same tool and takes the same options (such as `-F`).

Previously, the FAT tool names mirrored the Linux kernel driver names:

- `vfat` for all versions of FAT with LFN (long filename) support;
- `msdos` for all versions of FAT without LFN support (8.3-only).